# How to convert bigint into timestamp in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

How to convert bigint into date and time format and I have two column one is "state change date" and another one "state change time". I have to combine two columns and show in timestamp format. Please suggest a solution here. Thanks in advance.

I tried using Unixtime but it did not workout.

[image: Column details]

[image: Data type]

Comment: Is tags are fine now?

Comment: And please, do not post data as images. In this case data is text so post it as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using Unixtime but it did not workout.

Because your data does not look like [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), it looks like formatted date time stored in bigint for some reason. You can turn it into `varchar` and [parse](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format) correspondingly:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(state_change_date, state_change_time) as (
    VALUES (20220801, 355),
       (20220801, 2355)
)

-- query
SELECT date_parse(cast(state_change_date as varchar) || lpad(cast(state_change_time as varchar), 4 , '0'), '%Y%m%d%k%i')
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-08-01 03:55:00.000 |
| 2022-08-01 23:55:00.000 |

Comment: trino error: Cannot parse "20220803438": Value 43 for hourOfDay must be in the range [0,23]. I am getting this error.

Comment: @Nagahariprasanth then change the format. Since you have shown only data which suitable for the one I've used - I can't guess what is actually stored in your data)  What  `438` supposed to be? Is it 4 hours 38 minutes?

Comment: When I was using Azure (T-SQL) I used this code CAST(CAST(CONVERT(DATE,
            CONVERT(varchar,
            fii.inward_date,
            120)) AS VARCHAR)+' '+STUFF(
        RIGHT('0000' + CAST(fii.inward_time AS VARCHAR),
        4),
        3,
        0,
        ':') AS DATETIME). But now i am using presto

Comment: @Nagahariprasanth Then do the same here. Use `lpad(..., 4 , '0')`

Comment: @Nagahariprasanth please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Saw your question tags Presto but it seems you're using Trino (fmr. PrestoSQL). Just wanted to clarify that Trino is a fork of PrestoDB. The main Presto development is PrestoDB and you can download and install the latest here: https://prestodb.io/download.html.

Hope this helps clarify, the major differences are:

- Only PrestoDB is deployed reliably and in large scale at Meta, Uber, and ByteDance.
- Only PrestoDB has numerous innovations that aren’t in PrestoSQL: multi-level caching (project RaptorX) to boost query performance by 10X+, table scan improvements (project Aria), disaggregated coordinator (project Fireball) for better reliability, to name a few
- Only PrestoDB is hosted by Linux Foundation, giving confidence to community users that future releases will remain open.
  Feel free to join [Presto Slack][1] or use the [Slack direct sign up link][2]